# Want to log error message in database in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I want to store every error message and API endpoint in database so we to keep track of errors and I want to do this globally in the ASP.NET Core Web API project.

If any error occurs in an API call, I want the API endpoint, error message, and userLoggedInId. I want to do this dynamically and globally.

[database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jYUI.png)

Code snippet of solution and explanation

Comment: If using Serilog would provide more configurations.